# How to identify the blank page through script?

Tags: robotframework

Expectation is to verify the home page after user enters username, password and click login button. But sometimes blank page is displayed after clicking login button due to which script execution is getting failed. I would to like to re-initiate the execution whenever blank page is displayed. Blank page doesn't  occur during manual execution.  How to identify the blank page through script?

```
Input Text                         ${Loc_ UserName }    ${User_Name}
Input Text                         ${Loc_ Password }    ${Password}
Click Element                      ${Loc_SignIn_btn}
Wait Until Keyword Succeeds    60s    2s    Element Should Be Visible    ${Loc_Home_Page_Icon}
```

Comment: If you get blank page then it's UI issue which should be fixed by developer. When you get blank page again, open browser console log which should include some Javascript error and report it as a bug.

Comment: @BoburMeliev Since it is not reproducible in manual testing, not possible to check console log. It occurs only during automation execution.

Comment: How many times you should run automated tests to catch this bug?

Answer (score 0):

> But sometimes blank page is displayed after clicking login button

Get the element locator from the page which is expected to load after login.
Now check the status of that element whether it is present on the page and Based on the status try re-login. Something similar to...

```
${status}=   Run Keyword and Return Status      Element Should Be Visible    ${ElementLocator}
Run Keyword if   '${status}' == 'False'  Try Login Again
```